# Gradle: "Error: Could not find or load main class Main". Can't run file after build via Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build, jar, manifest

Stack Overflow

Faced a problem while building java app using Gradle.
After building the jar file, when trying to run it with

```
java -jar ZoneNewsDiscordBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

got this in terminal

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

**My project file's**
[hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y3Oi.png)

```
- ...
- .idea
- build
    - classes
        - java
            - main
                - Main.class
                - NewsGenerator.class
                - Resources.class
    - libs
        - ZoneNewsDiscordBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    - resources
        - main
            - META-INF
                MANIFEST.MF
            - application.properties
    - tmp
        - compileJava
        - jar 
            - MANIFEST.MF
- gradle
- img
- input
- out
- src
    - main
        - java
            - Main.java
            - NewsGenerator.java
            - Resources.java
- build.gradle
- gradlew
- gradlew.bat
- ...
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
 
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': "Main"
        )
    }
}
 
group 'com.ZoneNewsDiscordBot'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
 
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
 
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
 
dependencies {
    implementation "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.2.0_214'
 
    //for JSON parsing
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.11.3'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.11.3'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.11.3'
 
 
    //for uploading pictures from Web Page
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit', name: 'htmlunit', version: '2.45.0'
 
    //for working with Instagram
    compile group: 'com.restfb', name: 'restfb', version: '3.13.0'
    implementation 'com.github.instagram4j:instagram4j:2.0.3'
    compile group: 'org.brunocvcunha.instagram4j', name: 'instagram4j', version: '1.14'
    
    task stage(dependsOn: ['build', 'clean'])
    build.mustRunAfter clean
}
```

I tried to check MANIFEST.MF and got this
**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

Builded JAR-file (`ZoneNewsDiscordBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`) contains next files:

```
- META-INF (folder)
    - MANIFEST.MF
- application.properties
- Main.class
- NewsGenerator.class
- Resourses$1.class
- Resourses.class
- Test.class
```

`Test.class` is my temp class for some test things, I do not think that the problem is in it.

I cannot understand what the problem is. I has written right paths... Why it cannot find Main class?

Comment: JAR contains MANIFEST.MF (like in my post) and all compiled .class files in root

Comment: tried `java -cp ZoneNewsDiscordBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Main`. got the same problem `Error: Could not find or load main class Main`

Comment: files in JAR: META-INF folder (contains `MANIFEST.MF` like in my post); `applications.properties`, `Main.class`, `NewsGenerator.class`, `Resources$1.class`, `Resourses.class`, `Test.class` (my temp class for some test things,  i do not think that the problem is in it)

Comment: when i tried to use `javap` terminal says me that it doesn't know `javap`-command. same with `javac`-command, by the way

Comment: No-no-no. In META-INF folder is only `MANIFEST.MF` file. `applications.properties`, `Main.class`, `NewsGenerator.class`, `Resources$1.class`, `Resourses.class`, `Test.class` is in ROOT

Answer (score 0):

i solved it like this

This occurs because the class name including the package name is not written in the mainClassName entry of the build.gradle file.

EX)

1.

```
package example.sphinx;


public class ExampleMain {
  
}
```

```
plugin : 'java'
 
mainClassName = 'example.sphinx.ExampleClass'
```

2.Adding the application

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'application'
}
```

Comment: I paste it in build.gradle like

`mainClassName = 'Main'`


And now i can't build jar

Got this in terminal
`BUILD FAILED in 0s
Could not set unknown property 'mainClassName' for root project 'ZoneNewsDiscordBot' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: try adding application plugin

Comment: Added `application` in `plugins`. JAR builds successfully. But when i try to run it with `java -jar <file_name>.jar` got the same problem `Error: Could not find or load main class Main`

Comment: CLASSPATH variable
change it
```%JAVA_HOME%\lib;.```   Sometimes, it can also be caused by an environment variable problem.